# Associating types with each other

Tags: c++, c, dictionary

I have an `Action` class from which I derive several subtypes. Now, I need to associate some of these subtypes with each other, in a one-to-many relationship. The idea is that some types of `Action` subtype will make other subtypes available/unavailable (i.e. I also need to create them on the fly). Since in a language like C++ you cannot store type variables the only thing that makes sense is an association of string typenames.

Has anyone met a similar situation? And if so, would you simply use a non-unique associative container like `std::multimap` and then manually hardcode a huge switch statement for the string-type association?

Example: An action of type `Attack`will eventually make `Retreat` available to its actor, as well as others, like `Charge` etc. Each action constructor takes at least one `Actor` reference, but it may also take other, unknown at compile-time, parameters. This last bit makes it very difficult to model this as a decision/action tree... in other words, it seems like I have to build the decision tree during runtime.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do ?

Comment: The first idea I have is that there might be an architectural flow in your design. The inheritance model may be improved ? I often use map<Key_t, vector<Val_t>> for this kind of storage. Not perfect probably...

Comment: Trying to use a dynamic type system with strings is a very bad idea. It might help to know what are you trying to accomplish in the long run. Can you please make an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is the example above enough or should I go in more detail?

Comment: It sounds a little like a finite state machine might better serve your purpose, as they are good at modelling transitions that vary based on previous conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I may look into FSMs a bit more later on. I want GOAP really, and the algorithm is a GOAP one, but it may work with a modified FSM.

Comment: Are the associations static?  That is, does an `Attack` always imply that `Retreat` is available or are there dynamic factors that govern this?

Comment: No, and that's the problem with a simple FSM. The associations may change runtime.

Comment: you might not wanna get into it, but have you considered boost MPL/Fusion for this? they're very good at simplifying these sorts of problems

Comment: I haven't, but thanks for pointing it out.